# Installing Python with Ubuntu and raspberry Pi

Tags: ros, python, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can some one help me find the correct instructions for installing python with GPIO on my Pi.  I'm running ubuntu and I just finally got ROS to install and really don't want to screw it up....  Right now if I run a python script GPIO does not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223720/installing-python-with-ubuntu-and-raspberry-pi/) by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-09**:
What have you installed so far. What version of ubuntu are you using. You say it doesn't work, can you provide an example of what you do and what  happens  - do you get errors - if you do please post them

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-01-09**:
How do you talk to the Pins? I'd bet on missing privileges. I'm using the wiringPi library that provides ways to access to Pins also as normal user.

**Comment by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on 2016-01-09**:
I've installed a button on the Pi-2.  Example at: http://iot-projects.com/index.php?id=raspberry-pi-shutdown-button, worked fine on my Raspbian copy.  When I run it on my Ubuntu Ros version I get Import Error no Module named RPi.GPIO the basic python commands work... I believe I have Ubuntu 13.10

**Comment by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on 2016-01-09**:
Tried this, no luck
http://askubuntu.com/questions/295937/how-to-install-python-3-2-in-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works on raspbian because that has raspberry pi specific things like RPI.GPIO already installed. You will need to install that yourself on a more generic ubuntu system.

This is something that I think you will get more help from asking on the raspberry pi forums  as it is a raspberry pi issue, not a ROS one. For RPI.GPIO you need device tree support enabled in ubuntu, I don't know whether it is in 13.10 - there is a post here about getting it working with ubuntu 14.04 that might help https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=113014&p=773725
http://askubuntu.com/questions/621134/gpio-on-raspberry-pi

All the examples I have seen use 14.04 and upwards, and ROS support is better on 14.04. Is there a reason for using 13.10 (if that is what you have) ?

version 15.10 here https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ comes with RPI.GPIO pre-installed

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-10**:
I was getting mixed up - you need device tree support for the newer underlying mechanism that means you can use gpio with being root.

**Comment by [swilker](https://answers.ros.org/users/25514/swilker/) on 2016-01-10**:
Ok Yes spent the 2 hours plus redoing everything in Ubuntu 14.04, that's not the solution.  15.10 is made for Intel x86 and AMD64 the Pi is CPU: 900 MHz quad-core ARM Cortex A7 not sure they are compatible.  I'm thinking there is no solution.  Perhaps Raspbian with ROS... shoot!